# Solving unknowns of a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a list of formula stored in a cell array, and I solve the unknowns within the matrix.

```
For example, consider a 2*2 matrix:
[2x+y, 4q+z; 3x+0.5y, 2q+12z ]
```

How to solve q,x,y,z by setting each cell equals 20? (i.e., q= 4, x =5, y = 10, z=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking to solve a linear system. The canonical way to write a linear system is as `A*x = b` where `A` is a matrix, `x` is the vector to solve for, and `b` is also a vector. Writing your problem (in math) using matrices, the system is:

```
     [0   2   1   0        [q        [20
      4   0   0   1    *    x    =    20
      0   3  .5   0         y         20
      2   0   0  12]        z]        20]
```

To solve the system numerically in MATLAB:

```
A = [0, 2, 1, 0; 4, 0, 0, 1;, 0, 3, .5, 0; 2, 0, 0, 12];
b = [20; 20; 20; 20];
xsol = linsolve(A, b);
```

You could also do `xsol = A \ b`. A point of caution: both `linsolve` and `\` will solve the system in the least squares sense if the system is overdetermined (typically, system is overdetermined if A is m by n where m > n).

`xsol(1)` will give the value for q, `xsol(2)` will give value for x, etc...
Solution is `[4.7826; 5.0000; 10.0000; 0.8696]`

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve what you are looking for is to use the Symbolic Toolbox. Here is an example code to solve for q, x, y, and z.

```
syms q x y z
A = [2*x+y==20, 4*q+z==20; 3*x+0.5*y==20, 2*q+12*z==20];
S = solve(A,[q x y z]);
disp([S.q S.x S.y S.z]);
```

Output:

```
[110/23, 5, 10, 20/23]
```